# How can I find a user's google profile image (within an organization)?

Tags: php, google-plus

I have a custom built blog that I want to show a contributors page with profile pictures for each contributing member. The organization uses google apps and all the contributing members have Google / Google+ profile pictures.

Is there a way I can use each user's e-mail address to lookup their profile picture and show that on their profile page on the blog? Or do I need to have them sign in with google before this is possible?

Is it any easier if I am doing this within the organization since we use google apps?

Basically, I can see all of these users' profile pictures in my g-mail account - so is there a way to grab the pictures to be used on the blog they contribute to as well?

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API for searching profiles by email address. There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=64) you should star for updates though.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. What if I have every user [authenticate to the blog via google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/) - is there a way to grab a profile image via that method?

Comment: If you request access to the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` scope you can look up the users own profile which will contain a profile image link. https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth

Answer (score 0):

There's no link, apparently, but if they've got a public G+ profile, you should be able to simply manipulate the URL.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/123456{/reviews}
https://plus.google.com/123456
```

Comment: And how do you get images from these URLs?